# How to hide React container after its been clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

So I have an overlay flex container that when clicked adds nominations to a movie. How do I make it so that it doesn't appear and thus doesn't give the option to click it once a movie has already been nominated? The click event is located in the MovieList container where the handleNominationsClick function is being taken from props and adding it to the onClick property in the overlay.

Here is App:

```
    const [nominations, setNominations] = useState([]);

    const nominateMovie = (movie) => {
        const newNominationList = [...nominations, movie];
        setNominations(newNominationList);
    };

    return (
        <div className='container-fluid movie-app'>
            <div className='row d-flex align-items-center mt-4 mb-4'>
                <MovieListHeading heading='Movies' />
                <SearchBox searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} />
            </div>
            <div className='row'>
                <MovieList
                    movies={movies}
                    nominationComponent={AddNominations}
                    handleNominationsClick={nominateMovie}
                />
            </div>
            <div className='row d-flex align-items-center mt-4 mb-4'>
                <MovieListHeading heading='Nominations' />
            </div>
```

MovieList Component:

```
onst MovieList = (props) => {
    const NominationComponent = props.nominationComponent;

    return (
        <>
            {props.movies.map((movie, index) => (
                <div className='image-container d-flex justify-content-start m-3 col-3 d-flex flex-column'>
                    <img src={movie.Poster} alt='movie'></img>
                    <div
                        onClick={() => props.handleNominationsClick(movie)}
                        className='overlay d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center'
                    >
                        <NominationComponent />
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest storing the nominated movies in an object that provides `O(1)` lookup and pass the `nominations` as a prop to `MovieList` so the overlay div can be conditionally rendered. I am assuming your `movies` data has an `id` property (*or some uniquely identifying property*) to use. If your data doesn't have a unique identifier then I highly recommend augmenting it to include one so you can use a proper React key when mapping.

App

```
const [nominations, setNominations] = useState({}); // <-- object

const nominateMovie = (movie) => {
    setNominations(nominations => ({
      ...nominations,
      [movie.id]: true // <-- set movie nomination by id
    }));
};

return (
    <div className='container-fluid movie-app'>
        <div className='row d-flex align-items-center mt-4 mb-4'>
            <MovieListHeading heading='Movies' />
            <SearchBox searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} />
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
            <MovieList
                movies={movies}
                nominationComponent={AddNominations}
                nominations={nominations} // <-- pass nominations
                handleNominationsClick={nominateMovie}
            />
        </div>
```

MovieList

```
const MovieList = (props) => {
  const NominationComponent = props.nominationComponent;

  return (
    <>
      {props.movies.map((movie, index) => (
        <div className='image-container d-flex justify-content-start m-3 col-3 d-flex flex-column'>
          <img src={movie.Poster} alt='movie'></img>
          {!props.nominations[movie.id] && ( // <-- conditional render
            <div
              onClick={() => props.handleNominationsClick(movie)}
              className='overlay d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center'
            >
              <NominationComponent />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Getting "TypeError: props.movies.map is not a function" when clicking add nomination.

Comment: @JabbatheHutt That's your code. This addition has nothing to do with the `movies` prop. In other words, I'm assuming your code already works and you just wanted to implement hiding the nomination overlay. Check your `movies` state/value that you are passing to `MovieList`.

Comment: Yea, I just need the nominate overlay to vanish for any movie I already nominated. I am getting the type error after the edits.

Comment: @JabbatheHutt No worries. Can you either include your full component code in your question and/or create a simple *running* codesandbox of it that I can live debug?

Comment: Yea, apologies. Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-goldberg-htpn6

Comment: @JabbatheHutt Seems the fetch url doesn't work in codesandbox (cross domain), can you just mock the `movies` fetch/state for now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232133/discussion-between-jabba-the-hutt-and-drew-reese).